# How to solve this: can not find and load main class org.apache.spark.deploy.history.HistoryServer

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, cloudera-cdh

I'm a new on Spark. When I install the Spark on Cloudera, it appears this error:

> Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.spark.deploy.history.HistoryServer

The last lines of the log file are:

```
/user/spark/applicationHistory

Thu Sep 10 23:43:50 CST 2015

Thu Sep 10 23:43:50 CST 2015: Detected CDH_VERSION of [5]

Thu Sep 10 23:43:50 CST 2015: Starting Spark History Server

Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.spark.deploy.history.HistoryServer
```

My cloudera manager version is 5.2.5 and CDH version is 5.0.0. 
I have installed Yarn, HDFS and zookeeper, and they works well so far.

And there is a spark jar (spark-assembly_2.10-0.9.0-cdh5.0.0-hadoop2.3.0-cdh5.0.0.jar) at:

> /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.0.0-1.cdh5.0.0.p0.47/lib/spark/assembly/lib/

Thanks!

Comment: can you check if this class exist in this jar?
quick guide from cloudera on installing history server : http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/documentation/core/latest/topics/admin_spark_history_server.html#concept_iw5_d5f_qr_unique_1

Comment: I have checked it in Eclipse. However, I didn't find the class, even the 'history' package.

Comment: And now I decide to install it by myself. I recognize that CDH5.0.0 only has spark 0.9, which is not what I want.